# Run front end and Backend services in ECS fargate

Tags: python, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have a small `reactjs` front end application and a `python` backend application.

I am want to run these two services in the `ECS` fargate. So I created a `task definition` and included both containers in the in the same task definition.

And by `reactjs` app is talking (hitting) to the `python` backend using `axios` as below:

```
axio.get("http://127.0.0.1:8083/monitors").then(res => {
      this.setState({
        status: res.data
      });
    });
```

This setup is working perfectly fine in local environment. But since now I moved this to fargate, when I access the front end service with the domain, I get the following error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED 127.0.0.1:8083/monitors:1

so, how can I do this, how can I access the backend container?

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is the loopback IP address, it points to the same node that your code is running on. You need the address (IP or DNS) of the actual backend.

Comment: How can I do this? How can I get the IP of backend? Since this is fargate the ip address can change right? So in that case can you tell me what can I do?

Comment: @rdas multiple containers on ECS Fargate actually communicate with each other over `127.0.0.1` on their respective ports, it's a feature of the Fargate network stack. However in this instance the application is really running in the user's web browser, not Fargate.

Answer (score 1):

Your setup would work correctly if these were both backend applications. However, ReactJS applications actually run in the user's web browser. Axios needs to make a network connection between your local computer running the web browser, and the backend service running on Fargate. Currently, because you have it pointing at `127.0.0.1` it is trying to look for a service running on your local computer on port `8083` which does not exist.

You need to configure your Axios application to hit the backend service by its public IP address or domain. A load balancer is typically used in this scenario, and you would then point Axios at the load balancer's domain name.

Comment: If my backend and frontend services are attached to the same load balancer, how come the load balancer url can be used in this case?

Comment: What makes you think they are attached to the same load balancer? A load balancer target group will only point to one of the containers.

Comment: Yes, in that case, how is the domain name will be formatted? load balancer dns plus something?

Comment: And what if both services are in the same task definition? Then they are belonging to the same task group, in that case, how can we distinguish the two services?

Comment: My problem is how can we get this endpoint url as where I can see it?

Comment: You would create another load balancer, and another target group, and configure that target group to point to the other container in the task definition. Or alternatively create another target group, and use it on another listener, on another port of the load balancer. Right now it doesn't sound like your backend is accessible via any endpoint at all.

Comment: I would also point out that there is no need for these services to be in the same task group.

Comment: Can we not use the same `load balancer` for this?

Comment: Did you read my comment where I said you could attach another target group to the current load balancer? There is currently no "magic" URL that will send a request from the load balancer to the other container in the task. A load balancer target group doesn't point to a "task" it points to a single container inside a task. You will need to configure another target group.

Comment: I created another task definition and another service for backend in `ecs`. So it created a target group automatically. Now it is being attached tot he same load balancer. As you said, now, the load balancer has another target group for the backend. And I created a rule in load balancer and configured a domain in in route 53. (`backend.somedomain.com`. So now in my f,rontend can I call that `http://backend.somedomain.com:8083/endpoint` ?

Comment: Yes, although it may not be port 8083, it should be whatever the load balancer port is, not the container port.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228579/discussion-between-jananath-banuka-and-mark-b).